# sum of select cases into a temp variable

Tags: sql-server

Im trying to use select with cases and sum all values in the sum columns and store it in a variable.

```
declare @testmoney = 0

SELECT
   CASE
      WHEN (sum >= 500 and sum < 10) THEN 
         CAST((@testmoney + round(sum * 0.10, 0)) AS DECIMAL)
      WHEN (sum >= 1000 and sum < 20) THEN
         CAST((@testmoney+ round(sum * 0.20, 0)) AS DECIMAL)
      WHEN (sum >= 30) THEN 
         CAST((@testmoney+ round(sum * 0.30, 0)) AS DECIMAL)
      ELSE 0
   END as s, 
   sum
FROM 
...
```

Comment: You need to assign the output to something, and if you're aggregating you need to take amount out of the select list. [This fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1d9c8/67) seems to do what you ask.

Answer (score 0):

Try ..

```
    declare @sum money = 0

SELECT
@sum =
    sum(
    CASE
      WHEN (b.amount >= 500 and b.amount < 1000) THEN 
         CAST((@sum + round(b.amount * 0.03, 0)) AS DECIMAL (13,4))
      WHEN (b.amount >= 1000 and b.amount < 3000) THEN
         CAST((@sum + round(b.amount * 0.05, 0)) AS DECIMAL (13,4))
      WHEN (b.amount >= 3000) THEN 
         CAST((@sum + round(b.amount * 0.1, 0)) AS DECIMAL (13,4))
      ELSE 0
   END ) 
FROM 
bonus b
```

Comment: @Henrik Did you really try this query? [Worked for me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1d9c8/67).